# Azcopy Copy Millions of Small Blob from storage account to your VM

Tags: azure, etl, azcopy

I am trying to copy millions of small csv files from my storage account to a physical machine using the azcopy command, and I noticed that the speed has been very slow.

The format of azcopy command is
Azcopy Copy <Storage_account_source>  --recursive --overwrite=True

And the Command is ran from the Physical Machine.

Is there a way where you can make azcopy download multiple blobs concurrently? instead of checking the blob one by one? I believe that's why the speed is dropping to such a low value of 1 mb/second as it's doing checks on these really small blobs one by one. Or if there is another way to increase the speed of this case of blob transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

azcopy is highly optimized for throughput using parallel processing etc. I haven't come across any tools that provide you faster download speed overall. The main limiting factors in my experience are usually (obviously) network bandwidth but also CPU power. It uses a lot of compute resources. So can you maybe increase those two on your VM at least for the duration of the download?

Comment: Can you point me to where I can read about network bandwidth and increasing cpu

Comment: where is your VM? Azure?

Comment: the landing location is a physical machine, edge node of a hadoop cluster